# How do I use the hugo command to update a single file?

Tags: hugo

I have a working Hugo site. It has hundreds of pages. However there are times I just want to regenerate a single page.

I know that hugo is super fast, often rendering hundreds or thousands of pages per second. However in this case I’m trying to optimize a particular situation and the ability to just generate this one page is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to request Hugo to update a single file. This is mostly due to the fact that lots of Hugo parameters and functions require Hugo to analyze the whole set of pages to render (internal linking, page counts...)

The only way would be to set all the pages you don't want to update as Draft, but this would have an impact on the site for the reason mentioned above.

You can disable some pages kinds using `hugo --disableKinds strings`
See here: https://gohugo.io/commands/hugo/

If it is a speed issue, the best solution is to use `partialCached` instead of `partial`, to avoid rendering the same partial for each page. This improves the rendering speed significantly.
https://gohugo.io/functions/partialcached/